# Unfair Bounty System?

Tags: support, bounty

Recently I've [started a Bounty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16867/missing-thumbnails-for-swf-files-in-nautilus), which is about to end very soon (in less than 23 hours, to be precise). And just a few minutes ago, I received this E-Mail:

> Reminder: Your Bounty Is Ending Soon!
>
> Your bounty on the question …
>
> [**Missing Thumbnails for .swf files in nautilus?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16867/missing-thumbnails-for-swf-files-in-nautilus)
>
> … ends in 23 hours.
>
> ***Don't forget to review the answers and award your bounty by clicking the bounty indicator to the left of each answer. If you don't award your bounty, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount!***

The actual important part is bold. The problem is, that the highest voted answer doesn't answer the question at all, infact, it's merely a comment! How is this Bounty system in any way fair?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're missing is that only the answer provided *after* the bounty started with a score of higher than two will get the half bounty. Which would be [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16867/missing-thumbnails-for-swf-files-in-nautilus/22894#22894) answer.

The bounty system is *fair* because two people from the community thought it was a "good" answer. If you think otherwise you can always downvote that answer (as it appears to not have worked for you yet). If the answer is edited and solves or answers your question you'll be able to change your vote (if you please) and award the bounty.

Comment: I did indeed not notice this... Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score -2):

This should work: add a dummy answer to the question when starting a bounty, delete it, and if after seven days there's no decent answer, undelete yours, award the bounty, delete it again.

Comment: Cheating the system - not the best idea :)

Comment: Couldn't this also be used unfairly, so as to avoid awarding the bounty, even if you should?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi It's more exploiting than cheating. :P @luri Why would I do that? The rep points are gone anyway, and I think at AU we are mature enough to not act like "Oh, I don't like this guy, he's *so* not getting my bounty". I just don't see why I shouldn't be able to express "From my POV there's no answer that deserves **my** rep points".

Comment: I think this defeats the whole purpose of the bounty system and would be against the common ethics of the StackExchange community IMO.

Comment: The dummy answer will be deleted, and then, there goes the bounty!

Answer (score -3):

> The problem is, that the highest voted answer doesn't answer the question at all, infact, it's merely a comment!

If you don't like the answer that will be automatically selected for your bounty, then you should manually select an answer you *do* like!  In fact, you got the warning email to remind you that the deadline is coming up soon so you can do exactly that.