# Possible to split a bounty or award a partial bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

1. How do we award a partial bounty?
2. And how would we split a bounty up between several users?

And (3): I believe the two above are not possible, so is this the right place to ask for an enhancement of the system?

Ad 1) It seems the only way to award a partial bounty is to wait until the bounty expires and let the automatic system decide [("Unfair Bounty system?")](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/897/28323).

It seems even [increasing a bounty](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1265/28323) is not possible, so probably reducing isn't either.

Ad 2) For increasing I guess one has to close the first, immediately offer a second and award it, too.  Maybe this is a good practice to start offering a smaller bounty than wanted, and thus have some leeway to award a second one if a good second answer comes by.

[Not getting the reputation back](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/968/28323) is not a bad thing either, but I'd prefer if one would get back a certain percentage. I feel the temptation to just award the bounty to whoever tried to be helpful just to not let the rep vanish in the dark abyss.

And just for reference: This [discussion about duplicate answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1231/28323) does not cover bounties.

Any older questions/discussion I have not seen?

Update:
On stackoverflow there's a discussion of (2) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/170949) and someone suggesting the above mentioned workaround [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63825/170949).

Update2:
Hm, maybe this Q needs to (a) migrated to meta.stackexchange.com and then (b) closed as a duplicate. According to [Meta on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60819/170949) a question like mine which affects all sites, should probably be hosted and asked on meta.stackexchange.com.

And I guess ["Why is SE split into multiple sites"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64367/170949) applies to meta as well with the difficulty that users (like me) should learn when to post to the global meta.stackexchange.com and when to post to the individual site.

I will keep this Q open for a day or so, and if there are no other answers/opinions, I will move my updates into an answer and then request closure from the moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some searchingand after I waited some days for others to chime in, I come to the conclusion that:

Both (1) and (2) are not possible.

On stackoverflow there's a discussion of (2) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/170949) and someone suggesting a workaround [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63825/170949) which essentially means to close/award the original bounty, and then award a second one.

According to [Meta on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60819/170949) a question like mine which affects all sites, should probably be hosted and asked on meta.stackexchange.com.

Let me know by commenting or providing more answers if you disagree with my conclusion.